# mysql optimize invoice remainder query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

how to optimize the below query. eventhough this solves the issue , will anyone help me to optimize the query please.

```
select invoice_tbl.invoice_no, invoice_tbl.invoice_date , adddate(invoice_date , interval remdays day) as remainder_date , remainder_tbl.desc
from ( select max(id) as id,invoice_no
from invoice_tbl inv
inner join remainder_tbl where adddate(invoice_date , interval remdays day) <= now() group by invoice_no ) as remdetails
inner join invoice_tbl on invoice_tbl.invoice_no = remdetails.invoice_no
inner join remainder_tbl on remainder_tbl.id = remdetails.id
```

we have 2 tables , **invoice_tbl** and **remainder_tbl** .

```
 invoice_tbl
 -----------

*--------------------------------------------*
| invoice_no  |  invoice_date | patient_name |
|-------------|---------------|--------------|
| 1           | 2015-07-15    | xxxxxxxxxxxx |
| 2           | 2015-07-29    | aaaaaaaaaaaa |
*-------------*---------------*--------------*

remainder_tbl
-------------

*----------------------------------------*
| id  |  remdays | desc                  |
|-----|----------|-----------------------|
| 1   |  5       | First Remainder       |
| 2   |  8       | Second Remainder      |
| 3   |  10      | Third Remainder       |
| 4   |  15      | Fourth Remainder      |
*-----*----------*-----------------------*
```

when i run the query it should display as

```
*------------------------------------------------------*
| invoice_no | invoice_date | remainder_date | desc    |   
|------------|--------------|----------------|---------|
| 1          | 2015-07-15   | 2015-07-30     | Fourth  |
| 2          | 2015-07-29   | 2015-08-06     | Second  |
*------------*--------------*----------------*---------*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adddate(invoice_date , interval remdays day) <= now()
```

has `invoice_date` hidden in a function call, so `INDEXing` cannot be used. Change to

```
NOW() - INTERVAL remdays DAY <= invoice_date
```

And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can check for the right indexes.

And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see what the optimizer decided to do.